# What are these GPS data mean, and how to correctly convert them into decimal degrees?

Tags: gps, arcgis, data-conversion, arcmap

I have a set of household GPS coordinates data, and the format in excel sheet looks like the following (edited for confidential reason):

```
    ID    GPSN   GPSS   GPSE   GPSW
    1    211234   -9   890123   -9
    2    211255   -9   890155   -9
    ...
```

My questions are: what kind of GPS coordinates this is (looks like UTM data)? How do I accurately convert them into decimal degrees that only containing a longitude and a latitude (or X, Y data)? Do I need some kind of zoning information to do this correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that a GPS receiver would put out UTM coordinates. It looks to me like latitude and longitude in degrees/minutes/seconds (DDMMSS). If so, then one way to do it is the following, in simple Python. The [Convert Coordinate Notation tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/convert-coordinate-notation.htm) in ArcGIS might be useful, but you'll have to reformat the data first, probably using Python.

```
import csv
import sys

# A function that takes 211234, treats it as 21°12'34",
# and returns 21.209444.
def convertToDegrees(DMS):
    dms = DMS
    dms = int(dms)
    seconds = dms % 100
    if 60 <= seconds:
        print "More than 60 seconds! " + str(DMS) + " is not degrees/minutes/seconds!"
    dms /= 100
    minutes = dms % 100
    if 60 <= minutes:
        print "More than 60 minutes! " + str(DMS) + " is not degrees/minutes/seconds!"
    dms -= minutes
    degrees = dms / 100
    degrees += (minutes / 60.0)
    degrees += (seconds / (60.0 * 60.0))
    if 180 < degrees or -180 > degrees:
        print "In " + str(DMS) + ", degrees is outside [-180, 180]: " + str(degrees)
    return degrees

# Input and output files from command line parameters
inFilename = sys.argv[1]
outFilename = sys.argv[2]
readFirstRow = False
with open(inFilename, "rb") as inFile:
    reader = csv.reader(inFile)
    with open(outFilename, "wb") as outFile:
        writer = csv.writer(outFile)

        # Loop through the rows
        for row in reader:
            if (not readFirstRow):
                # Write the header row only once
                writer.writerow(["ID", "latitude", "longitude"])
                readFirstRow = True
            else:
                # Convert this row to latitude and longitude
                latitude = 0
                longitude = 0
                if "-9" != row[1]:
                    latitude = convertToDegrees(row[1])
                if "-9" != row[2]:
                    latitude = -1 * convertToDegrees(row[2])
                if "-9" != row[3]:
                    longitude = convertToDegrees(row[3])
                if "-9" != row[4]:
                    longitude = -1 * convertToDegrees(row[4])
                writer.writerow([row[0], latitude, longitude])
```

To make sure you get it right, you'll want to confirm that the GPS was putting out latitude and longitude and find out which datum it used (probably WGS 1984).

Comment: Thank you @Gary S., I checked with my data source, and it is UTM GPS data. -9 indicates missing data. They just lack the zoning information. Thanks anyway.